# How to protect my files from the Mobile repairers?

Tags: privacy

I'm using Samsung Galaxy Core GT model. I have some problem in my Mobile. I want to have my Mobile serviced, so I want to protect my photos and other data from the Mobile repairer/technician. I've heard that now a days those people are hacking the personal photos of the Mobile users. They are using the photos for illegal purposes.

So how do I protect the photos from those people before giving my phone for servicing?

Comment: Welcome to Android.SE! Your question is a bit unclear: what "mobile service person" are you talking about? Are you talking about repair service? // Please also take a look into our [privacy tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/privacy/info), which probably already holds the information you want. If my above guess was correct: [I have sold my phone on eBay. What should I do before I send it off?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4623/16575) / [What's the most complete way to erase all the data from my phone so it cannot be recovered?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/422/16575)

Comment: Just move all your important and private data to your computer via a usb cable or to your external sd card and remove it while you give it for servicing. Once you serviced your phone, copy those file back to your phone.

Answer (score 0):

If your really paranoid about your data then backing up all your information to your PC would be one thing - syncing your contacts to your Google account.

If you have a later version of Android then should have encrypting software to encrypt your device and data. But to be safe, anything personal backup to your PC.